# What does func.apply(this, arguments) do in this code for _.once()?

Tags: javascript

The following function underbar function was rewritten by peer of mine like so:

```
    var once = function(func) {
        var alreadyCalled = false;
        var result;

        return function() {
          if (!alreadyCalled) {
            result = func.apply(this, arguments);
            alreadyCalled = true;
          }
        return result
        };
      };
```

Here's how I interpret it. It's a function that takes another function and returns yet another function. If `alreadyCalled` is `false` then set `result = func.apply(this,arguments)`

Can someone please help me understand in a simple way what `func.apply(this,arguments)` is doing in the context of this function. I can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: store `this` in variable previous return function...

Comment: [MDN Apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two implicit parameters on every function: `this` and `arguments`.

The `apply` method on the Function object lets you invoke it with those parameters explicitly set.

So what will happen here is that you a get a function wrapping another, and when you call it it will pass down the arguments to the original.  It will also keep track if it was called and its result.

Comment: How come this `var once = function(func){
    var result = func.apply(this,arguments);
    return result;
};
addTwo = function(x){return x + 2};
once(addTwo(2));` returns TypeError: func.apply is not a function

Comment: You need to call it like this `once(addTwo)(2)` or else you are not passing a function to `once`, you will be passing in `4`

Comment: Or even better save a reference to the new function on a variable
`var addTwoOnce = once(addTwo)` and then `addTwoOnce(2)`

Answer (score 7):

remove async await from

```
React.useEffect(async () => { await something},[]);
```

then it works just remove async await

```
React.useEffect(() => { something},[]);
```

I know your code is different but i got the same issue i remove async from all of the project which was used within useEffect and i dint saw the error again anymore